# Delete special characters from the beginning and end of string

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a prettier way to delete some special characters (`{}[]()*?!^:|&"/\~`) if they exists in the first and the last position of a string called query. My way is pretty ugly but does the work.

```js
while(
    query.charAt(1)==":" ||
    query.charAt(1)=="{" ||
    query.charAt(1)=="}" ||
    query.charAt(1)=="[" ||
    query.charAt(1)=="]" ||
    query.charAt(1)=="*" ||
    query.charAt(1)=="-" ||
    query.charAt(1)=="^" ||
    query.charAt(1)=="(" ||
    query.charAt(1)==")" ||
    query.charAt(1)=="|" ||
    query.charAt(1)=='"' ||
    query.charAt(1)=="/" ||
    query.charAt(1)=="_" ||
    query.charAt(1)=='"' ||
    query.charAt(1)=="~"
){
    query = query.slice(1);
}

while(
    query.charAt(query.length-1)=="!" ||
    query.charAt(query.length-1)==":" ||
    query.charAt(query.length-1)=="{" ||
    query.charAt(query.length-1)=="}" ||
    query.charAt(query.length-1)=="[" ||
    query.charAt(query.length-1)=="]" ||
    query.charAt(query.length-1)=="*" ||
    query.charAt(query.length-1)=="?" ||
    query.charAt(query.length-1)=="^" ||
    query.charAt(query.length-1)=="(" ||
    query.charAt(query.length-1)==")" ||
    query.charAt(query.length-1)=="|" ||
    query.charAt(query.length-1)=="&" ||
    query.charAt(query.length-1)=='"' ||
    query.charAt(query.length-1)=="/" ||
    query.charAt(query.length-1)=="\\"||
    query.charAt(query.length-1)=="~"
){
    query = query.slice(0, -1);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a regular expression instead:

```
query = query.replace(/^[-:{}[\]*^()|"]+|[-:{}[\]*^()|"]+$/g, '');
```

This pattern is composed of:

```
^[CHARS]+|[CHARS]+$
```

where `CHARS` are the characters you want to remove.

- `^[CHARS]+` - Match one or more of those characters at the beginning of the string
- `|` OR match
- `[CHARS]+$` - one or more of those characters at the end of the string

Comment: i did it this way since this method solves even strings with length >1, as "Hello (Word!" Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using a regular expression as proposed in [CertainPerformance's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60844881/218196) should be the preferred solution.

But just to demonstrate that it's possible to improve this solution without having to use regular expressions (and for those who are uncomfortable using them), there are a couple of things you could do:

- Avoid repeated calls to `query.charAt`. You can store the character at the position in a variable. The character doesn't change inside the condition.
- Instead of using `.charAt` you can also access the character at a specific position via bracket notation. `foo.charAt(0)` is the same as `foo[0]`.
- Instead of writing out multiple conditions you can use a lookup table or a `Set`.
- Instead of chipping off characters one by one, find the *last* position from the start (or *first* from the end) that his one of your characters.

Also `query.charAt(1)` doesn't seem correct, that would get the character at the second position. If you want to get the character at the first position you have to use `0`. Like everything else in JavaScript, strings are 0-based.

Applying what I said above, you would get:

```js
function trim(str, charsStart, charsEnd) {
  charsStart = new Set([...charsStart]);
  charsEnd = new Set([...charsEnd]);

  // trim from the start
  let trimFrom = null;
  for (let i = 0; charsStart.has(str[i]); i++) {
    trimFrom = i + 1;
  }
  if (trimFrom != null) {
    str = str.slice(trimFrom)
  }

  // trim from the end
  let trimTo = null;
  for (let i = str.length-1; charsEnd.has(str[i]); i--) {
    trimTo = i;
  }
  if (trimTo != null) {
    str = str.slice(0,trimTo)
  }

  return str;
}

console.log(trim('-*&sometext&:!', ':{}[]*-^()|"/_~', '!:{}[]*?^()|&"/\\~'))
```

---

This solution is an improvement over yours insofar that `trim` is a reusable function. However it's should be obvious that using a regular expression allows a much more concise implementation.

I'm refraining from saying that this solution is more "complex" than regular expressions because the behavior of regular expressions can also complex and the logic presented here in itself is actually not complex (at least I hope it's relatively easy to follow).

Answer (score 0):

In case you cannot easily understand regex, you can do another way (still ugly, but maybe better than yours. Not tested.):

```js
const filter = '{}[]()*?!^:|&"/\~';//include escape yourself
const listChar = filter.split('')//
for(let i = 0; i < listChar.length; i += 1)
{
    const char = listChar[i];
    while (str.indexOf(char) != -1)
        str = str.replace(char, "");
}
```